# BigDecimal request get Parameter (String cannot be be converted in BigDecimal)

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

i have a problem with my college project, is about a hotel.

`idhabitacion` is `BigDecimal` and i need use `request.getParameter` to use variable `hb` and call `hb.getTipoh`

i tried with this code but i think is stupid

```
java.math.BigDecimal idhabitacion = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("idhabitacion")));
```

dont show me error but doesnt work

```
java.math.BigDecimal idhabitacion = request.getParameter("idhabitacion");
Habitacion hb = new ControladorHabitacion().getHabitacion(idhabitacion);
```

the error is `String cannot be converted in BigDecimal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, somehow request.getParameter("idhabitacion") is coming as a string.

if so, Can you try with a BigDecimal constructor, which has a String argument. Something like

```
BigDecimal idhabitacion = new BigDecimal(request.getParameter("idhabitacion"));
```